# laravel join statement includes both rows instead of only one

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

My query selects the data for movies but I only want to have one row in the join statement I use skip and limit but if I use the word "first" the query fails so at the moment I'm getting duplicates of data mainly two of them are the same because I have two rows of data in my join statement how do I get it to only select one row I have tried using distinct but it's not doing anything.

Query:

```
Movie::select(['movies.id', 'images.small as poster', 'title', 'release_date', 
    'movies.created_at', 'movies.updated_at'])->leftJoin('images', function($join) {
        $join->on('images.imageable_id', '=', 'movies.id')
        ->where('images.imageable_type', '=', 'App\Movie')->skip(1)->take(1);
})
```

Comment: The class movie or imageable_type

Comment: You make no sense in what your saying at all Hamelraj

Answer (score 0):

Use 
        ->groupBy('distintColumnName')
to select unique rows

Answer (score 0):

Hey @ONYX have you thought about using Eloquent relationships rather than building the select statement like that?

if you had the correct relationship setup in your Movie model then you could just say `->with('poster')`

Then you could just set this function on your Movie model

```
public function poster()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Images::class)->first();
}
```

or

```
public function images()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Images::class);
}

public function poster()
{
    return $this->images()->first();
}
```